# Perl debugger on Emacs: Clear screen (buffer)?

Tags: perl, debugging, emacs

Say I have long debugging session in Perl with `perldb` on Emacs (M-x perldb). The output piles up, and at some point it becomes difficult to navigate through it.

I can restart the debugger with <kbd>R</kbd>, but that doesn't clear up the previous output. Is there a command to clear up the output of the buffer of the Perl debugger without having to kill the debugger and starting a new session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `comint-truncate-buffer`.  This will remove all but the last 1024 lines from the buffer.  The size can be customized by changing `comint-buffer-maximum-size`.

If you'd like to have the buffer truncated automatically, run this snippet of elisp:

```
(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'comint-truncate-buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Debugger input and output is buffer contents like any other — if you want to delete it, just do it. For example, `C-x h C-w` (`mark-whole-buffer` followed by `kill-region`) works in `perldb` buffers just fine, and is the closest equivalent to a "clear screen" command in a text terminal.